# How do I install Rails 2 and 3 in the same computer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-2

I have Rails 3.1.1 installed on my computer.

I have to open a project that uses Rails 2.3.4.

How can I install rails 2.3.4 without breaking everything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend using [rvm](http://beginrescueend.com/)

Comment: Isn't that for ruby? I need Rails.

Comment: Right, but once you have two separate ruby installs (each with its own set of gems) you can have two separate Rails installs. Or, you can use RVM's gemsets to have separate Rails installs inside the same ruby install

Comment: @tony: Barley want you to use RVM's Gemsets feature in order to achieve per-project isolated gem environments.

Comment: @Tony, "Isn't that for ruby? I need Rails.", um... what do you think Rails is written in?

Comment: @theTinMan ok, my comment was a little stupid =P
I installed ruby 1.8.7 using rvm. How can I set rails gem to 2.3?

Comment: $rvm use 1.8.7@appname --create

$gem install rails -v 2.3.8 # or your version

Comment: I recommend putting .rvmrc files in your app root directories. Then the ruby will be changed automatically upon cd. It is easy to forget the "rvm use" thing.

Comment: @froderik very nice. I was not aware of that :)

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to checkout [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv). Highly recommended!

Answer (score 1):

For dealing with ruby best way is with RVM http://beginrescueend.com/
For securing your project use gemsets which will isolate any libraries for your project only.
http://beginrescueend.com/gemsets/

Also with bundler( http://gembundler.com/ ) you will have a way less pain with loaded in to application gems. You can use bundler for both rails 2.3 and 3.1